# Installing Ruby 2.7.5 on Mac 12.6.7 with RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

I've worked through quite a few github issues and other stack overflow questions that seem similar. I still can't successfully get RVM to find my openssl correctly or install 2.7.5 for React Native. I'm on OSX 12.6.7.

```
rvm reinstall 2.7.5
ruby-2.7.5 - #removing src/ruby-2.7.5 - please wait
ruby-2.7.5 - #removing rubies/ruby-2.7.5 - please wait
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/12.6/x86_64/ruby-2.7.5.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx_brew.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/x/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.7.5 - #downloading ruby-2.7.5, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.7.5 - #extracting ruby-2.7.5 to /Users/x/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.5 - please wait
ruby-2.7.5 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-2.7.5 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-2.7.5 - #compiling - please wait
ruby-2.7.5 - #installing - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make install',
please read /Users/x/.rvm/log/1688495709_ruby-2.7.5/install.log
There has been an error while running make install. Halting the installation.
```

Here's my /usr/local/opt

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 x  admin    27 Jul  3 11:58 openssl -> ../Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.1_1
lrwxr-xr-x    1 x  admin    28 Jul  3 11:55 openssl@1.1 -> ../Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1u
lrwxr-xr-x    1 x  admin    27 Jul  3 11:58 openssl@3 -> ../Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.1_1
lrwxr-xr-x    1 x  admin    27 Jul  3 11:58 openssl@3.1 -> ../Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.1_1
```

Error from .rvm/log/1688493800_ruby-2.7.5/install.log

```
/Users//.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.5/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /Users//.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.5/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    from /Users//.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.5/lib/rubygems/specification.rb:2430:in `to_ruby'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:846:in `block (2 levels) in install_default_gem'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:279:in `open_for_install'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:845:in `block in install_default_gem'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:835:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:835:in `install_default_gem'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:799:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:950:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:947:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:947:in `<main>'
make: *** [do-install-nodoc] Error 1
```

Error from .rvm/src/ruby-2.7.5/ext/openssl/mkmf.log

```
/Users/x/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.5/ext/openssl/extconf.rb:111: OpenSSL >= 1.0.1, < 3.0.0 or LibreSSL >= 2.5.0 is required
    /Users/x/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.5/ext/openssl/extconf.rb:111:in `<top (required)>'
    ./ext/extmk.rb:214:in `load'
    ./ext/extmk.rb:214:in `block in extmake'
    /Users/x/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.5/lib/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    ./ext/extmk.rb:210:in `extmake'
    ./ext/extmk.rb:572:in `block in <main>'
    ./ext/extmk.rb:568:in `each'
    ./ext/extmk.rb:568:in `<main>'
```

I'm confused why it can't find the right openssl version when I clearly have it installed. Thanks and happy to provide any missing info that might help debug the issue.

Answer (score 17):

I fixed this by removing openssl@3, installing ruby 2.7.5 and then reinstall openssl@3.

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl@3
rvm reinstall 2.7.5
brew install openssl@3
```

Comment: Logged-in just so I could comment that this worked for me! Stayed up all night looking for a solution to this. Thanks man!

Comment: I also logged in just to thank you for this.